# Error while implementing count in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, html, postgresql

I have created two tables in the database, products and shopping_list. I have given products a foreign key reference of shopping_list which is product.shopping_list_id.

I am trying to find the total products present in the shopping list in ruby on rails but I am getting an error.

I have given a text box to enter the value,and that value is stored in the database as total items.

But when I add new products in the database the quantity is not getting updated in the database.

My shopping_list table is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_lists
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  shopping_list_name character varying(255),
  shopping_list_status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'OPEN'::character varying,
  total_items character varying(255) DEFAULT 0,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT shopping_lists_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My product table is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  shopping_list_id integer NOT NULL,
  product_name character varying(255) DEFAULT 'null'::character varying,
  product_category character varying(255),
  quantity integer,
  status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'OPEN'::character varying,
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My Html document ie list in which I enter my value is this:-

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<% if @shopping_lists.blank? %>
  <p>There are no shopping_lists currently in the system.</p>
<% else %>
  <p>These are the shopping_lists in the system</p>
  <table border="1">
  <tr><td>shopping_list No.</td><td>shopping_list Name</td><td>status</td><td>quantity</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
  <% @shopping_lists.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
   <td><%= link_to c.id, {:action => 'get_product', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.shopping_list_name %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= c.shopping_list_status %>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><%= c.total_items %>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this shopping_list?" } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add new shopping_list", {:action => 'new' }%></p>
```

In short I want to implement the following query:-

```
Select count(*) from products where shopping_list_id = '';
```

Can you please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want this:

```
Select count(*) from products where shopping_list_id = '';
```

You can do:

```
Product.count(:conditions => "shopping_list_id is NULL")
```

Comment: Using `.size` is better; if the `Product` collection already exists, it won't run a 2nd query against the database.

Comment: @ kaeros I wat to implement this in shopping list.so can you tell me where to make the changes

Comment: @Deefour Updated my answer, i think this reads better. What do you think?

Comment: @ArseneW You want to get shopping_lists that doesn't have products?

Comment: @Kaeros i want to get the product count for a particular shopping list

Comment: @ArseneW `@shopping_list.products.size` In your case it is `c.products.size`

Comment: Where do I put this @Kaeros

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25082/discussion-between-kaeros-and-arsenew)